# Use maven + yguard

Tags: java, maven-2, obfuscation, jar, yguard

Has anybody used maven and yguard for obfuscating jar files?How to do so?

Comment: it does't work with me could you help me out please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031869/why-is-my-jar-contains-just-meta-inf

Comment: see this link: https://csetutorials.com/obfuscate-jar-or-war-file-using-yguard.html

Answer (score 4):

I have done obfuscation using `yguard` in `Maven`. I have used the maven ant run plugin to run the ant tasks.

Steps:

1. Refer to the `build.xml` in your `pom.xml`. Check documentation of `Maven Antrun` plugin. You have a lot of examples there.
2. Create the `build.xml` with the rename elements as required by your project/jar. In case you want to refer to the Maven references like project information, define them as properties in your `pom.xml` before the ant task is executed

Please let me know if this answers your question